# Prove a given sequence of real numbers is convergent

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis, limits

Given the sequence of real numbers $\{x_n\}_{n \in \mathbb N}$, we define $\{y_n\}_{n \in \mathbb N}$ where $y_n=\max\{|x_1|,...,|x_n|\}$ for each $n \in \mathbb N$. Prove that if $\{x_n\}_{n \in \mathbb N}$ is bounded, then $\{y_n\}_{n \in \mathbb N}$ is a convergent sequence.

My attempt at a solution.

If $\{x_n\}_{n \in \mathbb N}$ is bounded, then, it has a convergent subsequence. Call that sequence $\{x_{n_k}\}_{k \in \mathbb N}$. Note that if $x=\lim_{k \to \infty} x_{n_k}$, then $|x|=\lim_{k \to \infty}|x_{n_k}|$. This can be proved by the fact that $0\leq ||x_{n_k}|-|x||\leq  |x_{n_k}-x| \to 0$ when $k \to \infty$.

I was going to try to prove that $|x|=lim_{n \to \infty} y_n$ but immediately realize that this doesn't need to be true. For example: $\{x_n\}_{n \in \mathbb N}$: $x_n=0$ if $n$ is odd and $x_n=1$ if $n$ is even has two convergent subsequences.

My problem is I don't know what else to do, I would appreciate some guidance.

Comment: To show that $y_n$ is convergent, focus on the properties of $y_n$.  There are several facts about $y_n$ that you should be able to deduce directly from your above statements.  Do those facts help you to prove convergence?

Comment: @John right, $\{y_n\}_{n \in \mathbb N}$ is bounded and it is monotone increasing, I can't believe I didn't realize it before

Comment: @user100106  : the MSE system dislikes unanswered questions.  You can answer your own question, or John can answer it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show that $y_n$ is convergent, focus on the properties of $y_n$. There are several facts about $y_n$ that you should be able to deduce directly from your above statements. Do those facts help you to prove convergence?

Answer (score 2):

It is consequence of the following:

*If a sequence is monotonic and bounded, then it converges.*

Comment: As realized by the OP 50 minutes before this was posted.